# Why is the Vue app div not filling the whole width?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Just created my first view project and having trouble setting the width of #app to max width of screen. Are HTML objects not supposed to inherit their parents w/h?

I've tried setting width to 100vw and other solutions suggested on google/stackoverflow.

The index.html only consists of a body with a div with id="app".

[Inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F6yI.png)

````
<style>

@font-face {
    font-family: "Gotham";
    src: local("Gotham Medium"),
    url(./fonts/gotham/GothamRoundedMedium_21022.ttf) format("truetype");

    font-family: "Gotham";
    src: local("Gotham Bold"),
    url(./fonts/gotham/GothamRoundedBold_21016.ttf) format("truetype");

    
}

body {
  max-width: 1980px;
}

#app {
  font-family: Gotham,Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: inherit;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

</style>```
````

Comment: you may try to inspect the element and check the default body margin setting

Comment: It's likely a container element is not  full width (maybe HTML or BODY) If you use the developer tools > Inspect feature, you can usually figure out which element it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking margins and paddings. By default, it is not 0. Setting the margin and padding is not the best option, but here it should help.

```css
*,*::before,*:;after{
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```css
* {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

As the fastest way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions did worked but affected margin of other components as well, the following code was enough for me to make the app stretch and occupy full screen width and height.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}
```